# php open_basedir File() <- empty brackets

Tags: php, open-basedir

I have a server with ISPConfig3 installed, and I have a user with multiple websites and shared files.

I have a strange `open_basedir` problem:

```
Trying to include: /var/www/clients/client2/web4/web/core/defs.php
Warning: require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/clients/client2/web4/web:/some more paths.....
```

As you can see, `/var/www/clients/client2/web4/web/core/defs.php` is under `/var/www/clients/client2/web4/web`, which is in the open_basedir's allowed paths.

Any idea what it could be?

EDIT:

Ok, I found out that `defs.php` is actually included properly. After it ends, I get the "File() is not within the allowed path(s)" errors:

Notice that `File()` <- braces are empty.

I think it happens because of the `require`/`include` function maybe. I'm using fastCGI btw.

anybody seen this anywhere?

NOTE:

http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=51164

It does not appear under suPHP.

I found out that the problem is caused when using eAccelerator. switching to APC solve it!

Comment: You should write up your answer below and then mark it as the correct one after the timeout. This will help people who encounter this problem in the future.

Comment: problem is - it's not really solved. using suPHP instead is not a solution. hopefully i'll have it really solved (under fastCGI) in a few days. currently i have open_basedir disabled on some of my websites.

Answer (score 1):

It can be **fixed by flushing the eAccelerator cache** `rm -rf /var/cache/php-eaccelerator/*` and reloading Apache.

If you extend `open_basedir` due to previous too narrow path, the previous warnings stay incorrectly cached and reported again, although the code works correctly.

Other solution is to configure the web control panel /usr/share/doc/php-eaccelerator-*.*.*/control.php and to set `eaccelerator.allowed_admin_path`. Then Clear cache by browser and immediately reload Apache

On shared hostings it is a bigger problem. (because without flushing the cache the file being included stay there. Even disabling "open_basedir" does not prevent the warning. Also touching the file is not nice because a small edit like whitespace is not enough for re-caching and a backward edit returns the same problem.)